# Laravel Excel big export. Server error 500

Tags: excel, laravel, export

I try to export 15000+ rows:

```
 Excel::create(...)->export('xls')
```

I get server error 500. Problem with memory or other?

Comment: Can you check your logs to see what the error was?

Comment: You can see on storage>logs>laravel.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was memory limit error, not excel.  Problem solved by separate query-builder results:

```
  $count = $User->count();
  $off_ex = 1000;
  for($j = 0;$j < $count/$off_ex;$j++){
    $users = $User->skip($j*$off_ex)->take($off_ex)->get();
    //...
  }
```